# RestResponse is null on POST request using RestSharp

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, restsharp

I am making a POST request with RestSharp (on windows phone 7.1 client). I sent string to a service in a request body. Looks like the service is successfully called and it returns proper value (integer), however response object is null:

```
client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, (response) => {
    data = response.Data;  // response is null in debugger
});
```

I cant understand why is that so.

Comment: Have you monitored the actual request (using Fiddler-or similar) to confirm that there is an actual request being made and a response coming back?

Answer (score 0):

`<T>` isn't a valid value for that call. I'm not sure that would even build there unless you've wrapped it in a generic method.

Also, is the response coming back as plain text? What's the Content-Type returned? Most likely, you should just use `ExecuteAsync(request, callback)` without the generic parameter and grab the data out of `response.Content` which is a string of the response body. `response.Data` is for the automatically deserialized XML or JSON (or custom) response if you use the generic method overload that specifies a type to deserialize to.

Comment: There is no Execute method present in RestSharp for WP. But I changed it to client.ExecuteAsync without <T>. The response object is still null and i cannot access to its properties. The web service returns an integer value that I should get it from the response object (probably through Content property as you suggested).

Comment: If response object is null, is there anything in ErrorException?

Comment: ErrorException is null. I added try catch block, but there is no exceptions happening.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an ongoing issue with RestSharp asynchronous calls - for HTTP transport errors ErrorException object is useless (returns null). Check the StatusCode property if it returns with anything but HttpStatusCode.OK. StatusDescription is not extremely useful either as it doesn't match complete status message from server response payload.